# Problem in creating a sticky/fixed nav bar using css

Tags: html, css, fixed, sticky

I'm making a website where the top bar needs to be sticky where it is currently.
[image: normal page]

Please check the code on my git hub repository because its too big to accommodate
[my github repository](https://github.com/vaibhav0704/web-page)

basically I know that we can do it in 2 ways by making the div tag `position: fixed;` or `position: sticky`, but neither of them is working.
[image: position: fixed;]

[image: position: sticky]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you can simply use:

```css
.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

position and top is already explained by other user but width is also required to keep the navbar's original form or else the navbar's components becomes disfigured as it loses its position.
 **In Your first picture we can see that the components have become disfigured**

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your div has the following styles:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
```

The top can have whatever value you want. If you want it to be at the very top of the page with no margin, make it `0`, or else make it `10px` for instance is you want it 10 pixels below the top of the window.

This will make sure your div or header is always at that particular position no matter where you scroll.